# How to set the url while passing array from jquery to python function?

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, django, ajax, url-parameters

How can I pass a parameter from jquery to python method?

> JQUERY

```
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Grapes']
   function sendfruitstoPython() {
       $.ajax({
       url: 'Getfruits',
       type: "POST",
       data: { Fruit : fruits } ,
       success: callbackFunc
    });

function callbackFunc(response) {
        console.log("demo");
    }
}
```

> PYTHON

```
def Getfruits(request):
    demo = request.GET.getlist('Fruit')
    print("this is ", demo)
```

OUTPUT
this is  []

URL PATTERN :

```
path('Getfruits', views.Getfruits, name='Getfruits')
```

It tried this as well...

JQUERY

```
function sendfruitstoPython() {
       $.ajax({
       url: 'Getfruits'+ fruits ,
       type: "POST",
       success: callbackFunc
    });

PYTHON
def def Getfruits(request, fruits) :
    demo = request.POST.getlist('fruits')
    print("this is ", demo)
   
URL PATTERN
path(r'^Getfruits/(?P<Fruit>\w+)/$', views.Getfruits, name='Fruit'),
```

It gives me error he current path, Extractor/Getfruits[object set] , didn't match any of these.

In Console i'm getting this ..
Not Found: /Extractor/Getfruits[object Set]
[09/Nov/2020 18:27:56] "POST /Extractor/Getfruits[object%20Set] HTTP/1.1" 404 3340

Answer (score 0):

JQUERY

```
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Grapes']
function sendfruitstoPython() {
      var selfruit = Array.from(fruits);    
       $.ajax({
       url: 'Getfruits/'+selfruit,
       type: "POST",
       success: callbackFunc
    });

function callbackFunc(response) {
        console.log("demo");
    }
}
```

PYTHON URL PATTERN

```
path('Getfruits/<selfruit>', views.Getfruits)
```

PYTHON METHOD

```
@csrf_exempt    
def Getfruits(request, selfruit):
li = list(selfruit.split(","))
```